# Issue adding action helper in Ember.js to dynamic content

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to use an action helper on content that is being dynamically generated. I'm pulling data in and creating rows of records. Each record has an edit and delete button being added to it. The purpose is to monitor an event and pass it to the router. In another instance I have an event -> disableScroll being monitored when a user goes to enter a new record. This successfully executes as it's wrapped within:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="form">
    <a href="#new-record" {{action "disableScroll" on="click"}}>New Record</a>    

     ....
     ....
     ....
</script>
```

I want to replicate this with n number of edit buttons. The edit button is being appended to the data brought in by the model and pushed as a new field in the record.

```
row.push("<a href='#edit-record' id='"+variable+"'>Edit Record</a>");
```

Comment: Can you put together a JSBin demonstrating the issue?  I really have no idea what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by sending an event to the router when the user clicks the button in the view instead of trying to attach an action helper in the template.